# Why can't I set a wire apex class to a variable array in JavaScript?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm using Apex to query data directly from Apex. I have the Wire Service working correctly for HTML, but I want to be able to record my data to an array in my LWC JavaScript file.
Am I missing something or doing it wrong? Should I create a method instead?

**LWC JS Code:**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

// Importing from the "MapMarkers.js" file.
import { MapMarkers } from './MapMarkers';

// Importing from the "mappingBox" LWC.
import { SearchString, SearchState } from 'c/mappingBox';

// Importing from the "messageChannels" folder.
import { subscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import COUNTER_FILE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/updatecounter__c';

// Importing Apex "QueryData" code, to get Opportunity object and fields data.
import getOpportunityList from '@salesforce/apex/QueryData.getOpportunityList';

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Global Variables.
let SearchStreet = '20 abc St';
let SearchCity = 'boston';

var myArray = [];

export default class Mapping extends LightningElement {

    // ** Still in work **

    @wire(getOpportunityList) 
    opportunities;

    myArray = this.opportunities;
```

**Apex Code:**

```
public with sharing class QueryData {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityList() {
    
        List<Opportunity> OppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        OppList = [SELECT Id, Service_Address__c, Development_Rep__c, Name, Project_Type__c, CloseDate FROM Opportunity LIMIT 5];
    
        return OppList;
    
    }
  
}
```

**Refined Question:**
The reasons why I didn't create a method was that I need to be able to past this array to the "MapMarkers.js" file, and I don't think a LWC method can be import correctly to a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wire methods are asynchronous. That means you can't get the data during the construction of your component; `myArray = this.opportunities;` executes before `getOpportunityList` does. If you want to do anything with the data in Javascript, you need to wait for the data to load. Alternatively, using a wire handler allows you to correctly set the data when it is available.

```
    myArray;
    @wire(getOpportunityList) handleGetOpportunityList(response) {
      if(response.data) {
        this.myArray = response.data;
      }
    }
```

Or the construction you'll find in the documentation:

```
    myArray;
    @wire(getOpportunityList) handleGetOpportunityList({ data, error }) {
      if(data) {
        this.myArray = data;
      }
    }
```

Note that the data property will be read-only, so you will need to copy the data before you can use.

Comment: So, I'm trying to use the first code you gave me, but I am getting a error message called: **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"**

Comment: Sorry ignore the first comment, I found out the error, it was in my HTML file. Thanks!

Comment: I am still getting empty data for "myArray", when I call it via **alert("Test:" + myArray);**. Any idea? Should I be calling the method?

Comment: @Pinto The method is called for you. You're trying to access the data too early.

Comment: When or how should I access the data, so I can import it to my MapMarkers.js file?

Comment: @Pinto The wire handler (demonstrated in this answer) would be the perfect time to do so.